# How Spring invokes @Bean methods if @Configuration class contains unresolvable class refs

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, classloading

Spring can parse `@Configuration` classes using `ClassReader`s

Assuming that we have the following scenario

We have an autoconfiguration class with multiple `@Bean` definitions

One of the `@Bean` has all conditions passed while second `@Bean` have `@ConditionalOnClass` & the class is not present in the class path

```java
@Configuration
class CustomConfiguration {
  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnClass(String.class)
  String knownClass() {
    return "Hello";
  }

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnClass(MissingClass.class)
  MissingClass secondBean() {
    return new MissingClass();
  }
}
```

In this scenario, I have couple of questions

1. Does Spring Boot AutoConfiguration register the first bean into the `ApplicationContext`?
2. If (1) is true, will my breakpoint inside first `@Bean` method be hit during debug
3. If (2) is true, how is the `*AutoConfiguration` class get loaded into JVM as this class will refers to other classes (from second @Bean) which cant be resolved at class load time
4. If (2) is false, does spring generate a class at runtime with just the first `@Bean` method and invoke the method?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally speaking you should avoid using `@ConditionalOnClass` on a `@Bean` method for this exact reason. This situation is covered in the [reference documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.2.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-class-conditions) where using a separate `@Configuration` class to isolate the `@ConditionalOnClass` condition is recommended.

To answer your specific questions:

1. Yes, the first bean will be registered as long as the configuration class can be loaded
2. Yes, a breakpoint in the first `@Bean` method should be hit during debugging
3. It depends on how the class that cannot be resolved is referenced. If it's only used within the body of a `@Bean` method, the class should load successfully. If the unresolvable class is used in the signature of a `@Bean` method (typically the return type), the class will fail to load.
4. N/A

As noted in the documentation linked to above, rather than worrying about the scenarios described in 3 and what will and will not work, using a separate, probably nested `@Configuration` class with a class-level condition is the recommended approach. For your specific example, that would look like this:

```
@Configuration
class CustomConfiguration {

  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnClass(String.class)
  String knownClass() {
    return "Hello";
  }

  @Configuration
  @ConditionalOnClass(MissingClass.class)
  static class DoubtfulBeanConfiguration {

    @Bean
    MissingClass missingClass() {
      return new MissingClass();
    }

  }

}
```

Comment: Updated the question with an example

Comment: I believe the sample in my example will throw NoClassDefFound error

Comment: Yes, it will. Hence the recommendation not to do what your example is doing.

Comment: I added an example with the solution you proposed to the question itself. If it is correct, can you add that to your answer so that I can remove it from question. Thanks for your help!!

Comment: I've added the specific example of how things should be structured.

Answer (score 0):

Andy above answered the "how question", i.e how to use the library. But in this answer I've attempted to answer the why question

Here is my understanding

1. Spring reads the autoconfiguration file metadata from `/META-INF/spring-autoconfigure-metadata.properties` from classpath (one such file is present in `spring-boot-autoconfigure`)

   - This file is generated by a plugin based on the `@Configuration`
     classes listed under
     `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration` key
     within `/META-INF/spring.factories` file by `spring-boot-autoconfigure-processor` plugin
   - The generated file contains `@Configuration` class level annotations such as `@ConditionalOnClass`, `@AutoConfigureBefore`,
     e.t.c]
2. Spring builds metadata about each of `@Configuration` classes retrieved from the above properties file
3. Spring then evaluates all `@Configuration` class level conditions including `@ConditionalOnClass` against current classpath & bean factory. If conditions succeed, it loads the `@Configuration` class using standard java class loading
4. If we keep `@ConditionalOnClass(MissingClass.class)` at `@Configuration` level, spring simply does not load the class load the configuration class if the class level conditions does not evaluate to true, say if the class is not there in classpath
5. But if we keep `@ConditionalOnClass(MissingClass.class)` at `@Bean` level, spring will attempt to load our `@Configuration` class (assuming all conditions at `@Configuration` class level are satisfied) & we will get `NoClassDefFoundError` during class load

Overall, we need to follow @Andy solution because of this reason

@Andy

Appreciate if you can give your view on whether this is how Spring internally implemented the `@ConditionalOnClass` feature

Thanks